# Emplacing a struct in unordered_map, reference issue

Tags: c++, boost, unordered-map

I have the following definition for boost unordered_map

```
typedef boost::unordered::unordered_map<std::String, CLIENT_STATE> CLIENT_MAP;
```

Where CLIENT_STATE is an struct defined as follow:

```
typedef struct{
unsigned char state;

/* socket fd of the client */
int fd;

/* File path requested by the client */
char file_path [255];

/* Current file offset */
unsigned long int offset;

} CLIENT_STATE;
```

When I try to add an element to CLIENT_MAP using emplace, the CLIENT_MAP creates a separate copy of the element, not related to the original definition. i.e. any modifications to the original element definition, won't do any changes to the element in the unordered_map.

I was told before, that using emplace won't clone the my original element, it will place it directly in the container check the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22920562/adding-an-element-to-boost-unordered-map)

So what's the best way to let the changes to the added element in the container affects the original definition and vice versa.

This is what I mean:

```
    CLIENT_STATE new_client;
    new_client.offset = 5;
    client_map.emplace("Test", new_client);
    new_client.offset = 10;

    cout << client_map["Test"].offest;
```

The cout won't print 10, it will print 5.

Currently to solve this issue, after an element to the unordered_map I work on the returned std::pair and do the modification, but I think it is not efficient way to do that.

Comment: `emplace` uses its arguments as the arguments of the ctor - in the case of `unordered_map`, the ctor that is called by emplace is that of `::std::pair<key_type, value_type>`

Comment: So, what should I do to get what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`emplace`, allows an object to be constructed from the arguments passed into it without needing to create the object to be passed in first, saving an overhead by removing a copy construction which normally happens as the result of creating objects to be inserted.

You can achieve what you want by use of pointers

`typedef boost::unordered::unordered_map<std::String, CLIENT_STATE* > CLIENT_MAP;`

But using pointers might prove problematic for memory handling, like object deletion, etc.

You can consider using [*`boost::shared_ptr`*](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm), something like following :
*(I'm no shared_ptr/boost expert)*

---

```
include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

boost::unordered::unordered_map<std::String, 
                  boost::shared_ptr<CLIENT_STATE> > client_map ;

std::string s ="client1" ;
CLIENT_STATE *c1 = new CLIENT_STATE;
//c1->state, c1->id, etc
my_map[t] = c1 ;
```

---

If you needn't make copies of the objects stored in the map, you can use C++11's [*`std::unique_ptr`*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)

Comment: What about if I want to find a value using the key, the iterator returned will be a pointer to a pointer?
Since each object I have is unique. It's better to use unique_ptr correct?

Comment: @HA-AS yeah iterating over `client_map` which `shared_ptr` as key is pointer to pointer, first pointer is iterator itself that points to the value in map

Comment: I am getting errors when compiling the file, please check my edit

Comment: Could you please help me, what is the problem? Sorry I don't know how to edit this error well

Comment: @HA-AS Please do not edit the answer with a long error message - just tell the author the location of the error and the first error message from the compiler. I'm sure he'll look into it.

Comment: @HA-AS I just told you one of way to achieve this and I suggest you first study/read more about shared_ptr, instead of blindly copying untested code. Also don't add errors in any answers on SO, its very likely to be rejected

Comment: @xxbbcc the error is in my code using his method. So that is why I edited the answer

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to use `emplace`. What you want is called shared pointer semantics. However, for future visitors to this question, it may be useful to explain how to correctly use `emplace` with an associative container.

As @gha.st correctly commented, `emplace` will call the constructor of `std::pair<std::string, CLIENT_STATE>`, which will make copies of the `string` and `CLIENT_STATE` objects.

Since C++11, `std::pair` has an extra constructor overload taking a first argument of tag type `std::piecewise_construct_t` which allows the members of the `std::pair` themselves to be emplace-constructed. Observe:

```
client_map.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
                   std::forward_as_tuple("Test"),
                   std::forward_as_tuple(5));
```

Now `emplace` will call the tag-overloaded constructor of `pair`, which in turn will emplace-construct its two data members from the arguments in the forwarded tuples.

In this case, `CLIENT_STATE` is an aggregate type, so (before C++20) it doesn't have a constructor which we can call with an `int` like this. But the above is the general technique to use with typical C++ class types. The best we can do for an aggregate before C++20 is to move-construct it from a temporary:

```
client_map.emplace("Test", CLIENT_STATE{ 0, 0, "", 5 });
```

In this case, this is of no help because the members of `CLIENT_STATE` are not move-constructible, so a move is the same as a copy.